# How to call a phone number from ios native app automatically

Tags: ios, iphone

I want to call a phone number from ios native app

the code is like this:

```
NSString *allString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"tel:%@",phoneNum];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:allString]]
```

In IOS10.2, Some one can auto-call directly, but others got a confirm dialog.

So, what should I do to let all iphones can auto call directly?

Answer (score 0):

Use in your viewcontroller

```
func doPhoneCall(_ number: String?) {

    if var number = number {
        number = number.replacingOccurrences(of: " ", with: "")
        if let phoneCallURL = URL(string:"tel://\(number)")   {
            openURL(phoneCallURL)
        }
    }
}

 func openURL(_ url: URL) {
    let application = UIApplication.shared
    if (application.canOpenURL(url)) {
        application.openURL(url);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but not works for me, I want to know why my code works on some iphones but others got a confirm dialog.

Comment: Does the other iPhones ios version same? may be not.